# Implementing multiple TextWatchers on the same Activity

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext, textwatcher

I implement *TextWatcher* in the *Activity*:

```
public class Coordinate extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
......
```

Then

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ........
```

Part of my problem is that having more than one TextChangedListener causes the app to FC

```
txtDdLatDeg.addTextChangedListener(this);
txtDMmLatDeg.addTextChangedListener(this);
txtDMSLatDeg.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Then

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String c = s.toString(); // read Content
    // stuff to do later
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMSLatDeg)).setText(c);
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDdLatDeg)).setText(c);
    return;
} // End of TextChanged method
```

I need to be able to update one *EditText* and have the other two update on the fly.
I can only seem to make it works when only one *EditText* has the `addChangeListener`.
I also cannot seem to implement a seperate `afterTextChanged` method for the individual *EditText* fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then create them as instance variables:

```
TextWatcher watcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
};
TextWatcher watcher2 = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
txtDdLatDeg.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
txtDMmLatDeg.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
```

Comment: Not sure why but I still cannot get this to work with more than one addTextChangedListener declared...I will keep at it.

Comment: Ok...I solved it by using an if statement to check for focus:

Comment: `2 methods to implement:
- android.text.TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged()
- android.text.TextWatcher.onTextChanged()`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved this by using `onFocus()` on the *EditText* before the `afterTextChanged` method:

```
onCreate (Bundle icicle) {
    // Usual stuff here
    txtDdLatDeg.addTextChangeListener(watcher1);
}

TextWatcher watcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
    if (txtDdLatDeg.hasFocus()) {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String c = s.toString();
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMSLatDeg)).setText(c); 
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMmLatDeg)).setText(c);     
        }
}};
```

I create an instance variable for each *EditText* box I need to watch/manipulate.